# How to convert 'Postgresql' biginteger type into integer in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

Here is my method:

```
def onchange_book_limit(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None)   
    if partner_id:
       cr.execute(""" select count(*) from rmkbook_issue where retflag!= 1 and partner_id = %s """ %(partner_id))
       cnt=cr.fetchone()
       cnt1=integer(cnt[0])
       if(cnt1 > 3):
           cr.execute("""insert into testwizard(orderid1) values(%s)""" %(cnt1))
           raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'), _('Sorry...You have exceeds the limit to take a book....!'))

    return partner_id
```

Comment: How have you tried to convert it? How did it fail? Did you get any exceptions? People need more information than this in order to help you.

Comment: What database driver is in use here? `psycopg2`? Something else? Python version? Please show the **exact text** of the error message you get.

Comment: it get solved just hv to add the suffix [0] after cnt1 in the insert query i.e. ------> 
           cr.execute("""insert into testwizard(orderid1) values(%s)""" %(cnt1[0]))